# Conditional formatting skipping colors after the same large value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Looks like the conditional formatting skipping large formula because of the same large values.

Help me please how can I get the order what is on the picture in the column "What I would like".

[image]

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_3ttVxisvIcX6vDINNtFNsEk6Sa0uSB9PYU-MqM09ds/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**red:**


```
=C2=LARGE(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"),1)
```

**orange:**


```
=C2=LARGE(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"),2)
```

**yellow:**


```
=OR(C2=LARGE(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"),3),
    C2=LARGE(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"),4))
```

**blue:**


```
=C2=LARGE(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"),5)
```

**green:**


```
=OR(C2=LARGE(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"),6),
    C2=LARGE(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"),7),
    C2=LARGE(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"),9))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thx, but unfortunately I cannot use this. As I cannot say for fix the large 3 and 4 are going to be yellow. Maybe large 4 is going to be blue. The data behind are changing every day and today for example the large 2 and 3 are the same but large 3 and 4 are different.

Comment: then not sure how can I help more